# Подскажите в чём ошибка, не запускается app react после закрытия

Tags: ubuntu, reactjs

Запуская в виртуальной машине Ubuntu, через командную строку создал проект (create-react-app), запустил написал немного кода, затем закрыл редактор кода, браузер и виртуальную машину. На следующий день запускаю виртуальную машину, захожу в ком. строку (в нужную папку с проектом) прописываю `npm start` и вылетает ошибка (прикреплённая), приходится удалять модули и выполнять заново install, и так каждый раз, поработал ушёл на след. день ошибка. Возможно нужно как то останавливать запуск сервера или что-то где-то сохранять\выключать? Подскажите в чём дело?

Спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `watch` вылетает с ошибкой `ENOSPC`, то скорее всего Вам поможет:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

По умолчанию в большинстве дистрибутивов лимит `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` для разработчиков слишком мал.

Comment: Прописал, после запустилось. Если возможно можете пожалуйста пояснить что именно эта строчка изменяет и собственно в чём была проблема? Как я понимаю это какое то ограничение по памяти? Однако у коллег я спрашивал они с подобным не сталкивались, а у меня на 2 пк (вирт. машина) и стац. с основной системой - одна и та же ошибка

Comment: Linux для отслеживания изменений в файлах создает в памяти таблицу где регистрируются все факты изменений. Обычно её размер ограничен (примерно 8k) т.к. это лишний расход памяти. WebPack сервер при отладке отслеживает очень большое количество файлов и к тому-же ещё и мусорные от предыдущих запусков, так что стандартный лимит очень быстро исчерпывается.